# jdev.conf not found after installing Oracle Jdeveloper 12C

Tags: oracle, configuration-files, soa, jdeveloper

I installed Oracle Jdeveloper 12C. Now, I want to start server instance (IntegratedWebLogicServer).

I am getting the error - `Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin"\bin;"=="" was unexpected at this time.`

So, I want to set the JDK to the right path.

I am trying to locate `jdev.conf` file in `JDEV_HOME\jdeveloper\jdev\bin` location.

But, I do not have such conf file. Infact I dont have folders jdev\bin inside jdeveloper. Why do I not have the `jdev.conf` file and how can I edit the JDK path?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your JDK to a directory that doesn't have a space in the path (not under Program Files), and then re-install JDev.

Comment: I just installed JDK to D:\  , modified environment variable and started the server in Jdeveloper. That error is gone. I didn't re-install Jdeveloper.